# Johansen test accepts first null hypothesis but would reject last one

Tags: time-series, matrix, linear-algebra, cointegration, eigenvalues

Suppose that we perfrom a Johansen test over three I(1) variables that give us these results through the maximum eigenvalues statistic:

[image]

as you can see, we accept the null hypothesis in the first step (highest eigenvalue), so in theory we should stop and assume that there is no cointegration between the variables.

However, for the lowest eigenvalue, we could reject the null hypothesis for 10% and 5% confidence level, so my question is: why don't consider the last eigenvalue test as the proof that there is a cointegration relationship and why do we stop in the first step?

Note: my question is fundamented in the fact that I believe the Johansen test is actually testing the rank of the matrix through the nullity + rank theorem, which states that the number of variables in a matrix (columns) - the nullity of a Matrix (the dimension of the eigenspace associated with an eigenvalue of 0) is equal to the rank. So, if I were right, in this case, rejecting the null hypothesis that the last eigenvalue is equal to 0 would mean that the rank of the matrix is at least 1, since the nullity couldn't be as high as the number of variables. Would be gradeful if anyone could give me an explanation in case my supposition is wrong.